# TikZ - Surrounding som edges of a "forest" tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I'm looking for some help to obtain a better formatting than what my code does for the moment : see the ugly picture below.

1. I would like the blue line to be parallel to "its" parallel edges.
2. I would also like to have the same distance from the blue lines to "its" parallel edges.

Is it possible ? Is there a (semi)automatic solution to do all of that ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestset{
    declare count   = {connections}{1},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
        for tree = {%
            sn edges,
            grow'  = 0,
            l      = 2.5cm,
            s sep  = 1.2cm,
            anchor = parent,
        },
        before typesetting nodes = {%
            where connections = 1{}{%
                if = {isodd(connections())}{%
                    edge path' = {%
                        foreach \i [
                            count    = \j from 0,
                            evaluate = \noexpand\j
                            as \noexpand\k
                            using \noexpand {
                                (\j == 0) ?
                                0pt :
                                ((isodd(\j)) ?
                                (\j*4pt) :
                                ((-\j + 1)*4pt))
                            }
                        ]
                        in {%
                            1, ..., \foresteoption{connections}
                        }{
                            (!u.parent anchor)
                            --
                            ([yshift = \noexpand\k].child anchor)
                        }
                    },
                }{%
                    edge path' = {%
                        foreach \i [
                            count    = \j,
                            evaluate = \noexpand\j
                            as \noexpand\k
                            using {
                                (isodd(\j)) ?
                                (\j*4pt) :
                                ((-\j + 1)*4pt)
                            }
                        ]
                        in {1,...,\foresteoption{connections}}
                        {
                            (!u.parent anchor)
                            --
                            ([yshift = \noexpand\k].child anchor)
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
        },
   %%%%
   [{}, name = start
        [$A$, name = nA
            [$B$]
            [$C$, name    = nC]
        ]
        [$D$,
            [$E$]    
            [$F$]
        ]
    ]
    \draw[blue,
          rounded corners,
          dashed,
          line width=0.7pt]          
    (start.90) --
    (nA.135) --
    (nA.45) --
    (nC.45) --
    (nC.315) --
    (nC.225) --
    (nA.315) --
    (nA.225) --
    (start.315) --
    (start.180) --
    (start.90);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A common trick is `\draw[blue, line width = 20.8pt]...` followed by  `\draw[white, line width = 20pt]...`.

Comment: Thanks for this starting point that also needs to play with z-indexes to avoid the hiding of the tree. The parallelsim remains wrong. Any tip ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't very difficult to add something that is parallel to the edges, but I doubt that this is what you really want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestset{
    declare count   = {connections}{1},
}

\tikzset{parallel path/.style args={#1--#2}{insert path={
       ($(#1)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallel distance}!90:(#2)$)
        -- ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallel distance}!-90:(#1)$)
}},parallel distance/.initial=1em
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
        for tree = {%
            sn edges,
            grow'  = 0,
            l      = 2.5cm,
            s sep  = 1.2cm,
            anchor = parent,
        },
        before typesetting nodes = {%
            where connections = 1{}{%
                if = {isodd(connections())}{%
                    edge path' = {%
                        foreach \i [
                            count    = \j from 0,
                            evaluate = \noexpand\j
                            as \noexpand\k
                            using \noexpand {
                                (\j == 0) ?
                                0pt :
                                ((isodd(\j)) ?
                                (\j*4pt) :
                                ((-\j + 1)*4pt))
                            }
                        ]
                        in {%
                            1, ..., \foresteoption{connections}
                        }{
                            (!u.parent anchor)
                            --
                            ([yshift = \noexpand\k].child anchor)
                        }
                    },
                }{%
                    edge path' = {%
                        foreach \i [
                            count    = \j,
                            evaluate = \noexpand\j
                            as \noexpand\k
                            using {
                                (isodd(\j)) ?
                                (\j*4pt) :
                                ((-\j + 1)*4pt)
                            }
                        ]
                        in {1,...,\foresteoption{connections}}
                        {
                            (!u.parent anchor)
                            --
                            ([yshift = \noexpand\k].child anchor)
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
        },
   %%%%
   [{}, name = start
        [$A$, name = nA
            [$B$]
            [$C$, name    = nC]
        ]
        [$D$,
            [$E$]    
            [$F$]
        ]
    ]
    \path
    [parallel path={nA.child anchor--start.parent anchor}]
    coordinate[pos=0] (p0) coordinate[pos=1] (p1)
    [parallel path={start.parent anchor--nA.child anchor}]
     coordinate[pos=0] (p2)  coordinate[pos=1] (p3)
    [parallel path={nA.parent anchor--nC.child anchor}]
     coordinate[pos=0] (p4)  coordinate[pos=1.1] (p5)
    [parallel path={nC.child anchor--nA.parent anchor}]
     coordinate[pos=-0.1] (p6)  coordinate[pos=1] (p7)
    ; 
    \draw[blue,dashed,line width=0.7pt]          
    let \p1=($(p0)-(p1)$),
    \p2=($(p4)-(p5)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
    \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
    \n3={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallel distance}} in 
    (p0) -- (p1) arc[start angle=\n1-90,end angle=\n1-270,radius=\n3] 
    -- (p3) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (p4) -- (p5)
    arc[start angle=\n2-90,end angle=\n2-270,radius=\n3] 
    -- (p7) to[out=\n2,in=\n1] cycle;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously the problem is that `C` is east of the anchor, and not just further down the edge.

Most of your code doesn't get used, and if one drops the `sn edges` there edges are nice and one gets

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{parallel path/.style args={#1--#2}{insert path={
       ($(#1)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallel distance}!90:(#2)$)
        -- ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallel distance}!-90:(#1)$)
}},parallel distance/.initial=1em
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
        for tree = {%
            grow'  = 0,
            l      = 2.5cm,
            parent anchor=east,
            s sep  = 1.2cm,
        },
   [{}, name = start,anchor=east
        [$A$, name = nA
            [$B$]
            [$C$, name    = nC]
        ]
        [$D$,
            [$E$]    
            [$F$]
        ]
    ]
    \path
    [parallel path={nA.child anchor--start.parent anchor}]
    coordinate[pos=0.2] (p0) coordinate[pos=1] (p1)
    [parallel path={start.parent anchor--nA.child anchor}]
     coordinate[pos=0] (p2)  coordinate[pos=1] (p3)
    [parallel path={nA.parent anchor--nC.child anchor}]
     coordinate[pos=0] (p4)  coordinate[pos=1.02] (p5)
    [parallel path={nC.child anchor--nA.parent anchor}]
     coordinate[pos=-0.02] (p6)  coordinate[pos=0.8] (p7)
    ; 
    \draw[blue,dashed,line width=0.7pt]          
    let \p1=($(p0)-(p1)$),
    \p2=($(p4)-(p5)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
    \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
    \n3={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallel distance}} in 
    (p0) -- (p1) arc[start angle=\n1-90,end angle=\n1-270,radius=\n3] 
    -- (p3) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (p4) -- (p5)
    arc[start angle=\n2-90,end angle=\n2-270,radius=\n3] 
    -- (p7) to[out=\n2,in=\n1] cycle;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! I will try to make this usable as a "macro". The ideau is to explain to beginners the path that is used.